How to Create Persistent Notifications in Android 14 for a Location Tracking App?
I'm developing an Android app that relies on persistent notifications to track location. Previously, I used

setOngoing(true)

to make the notification non-dismissible. However, with Android 14, users can now dismiss these notifications even if setOngoing(true) is set.
Here is the relevant documentation about this behavior change: Android 14 Behavior Changes - Non-Dismissable Notifications.
Here's my current code for the notification:
private Notification getNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Location Service")
            .setContentText("Running")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.trailmaplogo_foreground)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    return builder.build();
}

In my app, it's crucial to have a persistent notification that cannot be dismissed by the user under normal circumstances using swipe control, as it is not a media app but a location tracking app. Given the changes in Android 14, is there any workaround to achieve this?

If this is for some corporate app, look into the "Device policy controller (DPC) and supporting packages for enterprise" option. If this is for your own custom device, you probably can find a way to revert this in your custom firmware for that device.

I'm not a devloper, so I can't tell you exactly what code should be run, but in researching this issue for my Home Assistant setup (which of course also lost the ability for persistent notifications), I've found most people suggest sending the notification again if it's detected that the user swiped it away.
Good luck!
